# How to express "He puffed out his cheeks and at the same time spit out and possibly made some bubble sound"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> [puff out](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/puff-out) 1. PHRASAL VERB
>
> If you puff out your cheeks, you make them larger and rounder by
>   filling them with air.
>
> He puffed out his fat cheeks and let out a lungful of steamy breath.
>   [VERB PARTICLE noun]

[image]

The term "**puff out**" doesn't carry the meaning of spitting saliva out.

So, How to express "**He puffed out his cheeks and at the same time spit out and possibly made some bubble sound**"?

Comment: Why do you want to express that particular idea? What is the context?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, because my child did it & I I don't know how to express it.

Comment: How about "He puffed up his cheeks, drooled and burbled." How would you say it in your native language?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, Thanks a lot, I think "He puffed up his cheeks and drooled" may be enough